# how to check the input value is html encoded

Tags: jquery, html-encode

is there any way to check if a text box value is already html encoded or not.

For page validation i am using the following code on focus out of a textbox.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txtLink').focusout(function(){
            $('#txtLink').val(htmlEncode($('#txtLink').text()));
        });
    });
    function htmlEncode(value){
        if (value) {
            return jQuery('<div />').text(value).html();
        } 
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    function htmlDecode(value) {
        if (value) {
            return $('<div />').html(value).text();
        } 
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

for every focus out of the text box or alt+tab to other window etc... text is encoding multiple times.
need some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you html encoding the value when placing it as the val of `txtLink`?  Do you want it to show up as `<div>` in the `txtLink` or as `&lt;div&gt;` ?

Comment: there are multiple post back events on the page other than submit. So i didn't find another solution.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  I think you're confusing clien side and server side efforts.  When you set a val of an element that happens to contain HTML entities on the server side, you have to encode it because it needs to know that all that text is a part of the value and NOT new markup.  When client side, you can just set the value, e.g. `$('#txtLink').val('<div>Hello <span>World</span></div>')`  No encoding/decoding necessary for setting or retrieving (or posting).

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are right. i have no problem in showing the encoded value in the text box. it is in admin section.

Comment: So is your question closed or is there something else?  If so, either delete it or tell me to submit my comments as an answer so you can accept it and so others can search the result in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: yes my question is closed. But can you tell me the code for finding out the text is encoded or not. You can submit your comment as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know what you mean -- tell if it is encoded or not.  By the time the value is available to client side, the encoding you did on the server side is reinterpreted as literal values.  So if you check the val of `txtLink` it's going to be `<div>` and not `&lt;div&gt;` even though server side you set `value="&lt;div&gt;"` in the encoded format.  If you want to then escape `<div>` and save it as the escapped version `&lgt;div&gt;` I would still post `<div>` to the server (unencoded/unescaped) and then escape it server side.

Comment: oh.. thanks again. my question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing client side and server side efforts. When you set a val of an element that happens to contain HTML entities on the server side, you have to encode it because it needs to know that all that text is a part of the value and NOT new markup. When client side, you can just set the value, e.g. `$('#txtLink').val('<div>Hello <span>World</span></div>')` No encoding/decoding necessary for setting or retrieving (or posting)